# What can i use instead of after_destroy in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The API Doc says that this callback is deprecated since version 2.3.8, and I'm using Rails 4.2 , is there any existent function that resembles it?

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use "after_commit" instead of "after_destroy"

```
after_commit :do_baz, on: :destroy
```

Please refer to this link 
[rails doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods/after_commit)